# Docusign emails seem to always have the same subject

Tags: docusignapi

This is thru the Docusign api. Here is the envelope definition:

```
 {
  "eventNotification": {
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Delivered"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Voided"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Sent"
      }
    ],
    "useSoapInterface": "false",
    "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
    "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
    "includeDocuments": "false",
    "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "false",
    "includeTimeZone": "true",
    "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
    "includeDocumentFields": "true",
    "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false"
  },
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "c110d14a-3690-4ed1-921d-a7bef9524ed6"
        }
      ],
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "name": "Kathy Lori",
                "email": "kathylori@xxx.com",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "accessCode": "12345",
                "customFields": [],
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "note": "",
                "roleName": "##Buyer1"
              }
            ],
            "certifiedDeliveries": []
          },
          "customFields": {
            "textCustomFields": [
              {
                "name": "EnvelopeInfo",
                "value": "my data"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "document": {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "c:\three of the test.docx",
        "fileExtension": ".docx",
        "documentFields": [],
        "documentBase64": [bytearray]
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "This is the new subject"
}
```

The subject still shows as "Please DocuSign: sign this". I would have thought setting the subject would have addressed this, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have most likely configured **per recipient** email subject in your server template. In such a case the emailSubject that is specified at the root level of the postEnvelope request is ignored.

You can confirm that by making a [getTemplates](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/get/) call using your server template Id. It will look something like below. Look specifically for **recipients.signers.emailNotification** property.  *I have removed some of the properties for simplicity.*

```
 {
   "envelopeTemplateDefinition": {
     "templateId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e672c4efd436",
   },
   "documents": [ ],
   "emailSubject": "This is the subject on the server template.",
   "emailBlurb": "",
   "recipients": {
     "signers": [
       {
         "tabs": {},
         "roleName": "RoleOne",
         "emailNotification": {
           "emailSubject": "Please DocuSign: sign this",
           "emailBody": "",
           "supportedLanguage": "en"
         },
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```

To override the per recipient email subject specified in the server template, specify the **emailNotification** property in the inlineTemplate.

```
 {
   "compositeTemplates": [
     {
       "serverTemplates": [
         {
           "sequence": "1",
           "templateId": "c110d14a-3690-4ed1-921d-a7bef9524ed6"
         }
       ],
       "inlineTemplates": [
         {
           "sequence": "2",
           "recipients": {
             "signers": [
               {
                 "name": "Kathy Lori",
                 "email": "kathylori@xxx.com",
                 "recipientId": "1",
                 "accessCode": "12345"
                 "routingOrder": "1",
                 "roleName": "##Buyer1",
                "emailNotification": {
                          "emailSubject": "This is email subject to Buyer1",
                          "emailBody": "",
                          "supportedLanguage": "en"
                        },
               }
             ],
           }
         }
       ],
       "document": { }
     }
   ],
   "status": "sent",
 }
```